# Express.js req.files.myFile.type is missing

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express 3.4.0. And when I upload a file there is no such property  as `req.files.myFile.type` in req.files as it [described in documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.files). But there is `req.files.myFile.headers['content-type']` property. So the question is: am I doing something wrong or there are some changes in API that not depicted in documentation? In other words should I use `req.files.myFile.headers['content-type']` or should I try to get back `req.files.myFile.type`?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/911

multipart is deprecated now anyways.